# Wix installer: how to create start menu shortcuts for Win7 and Win10 in same installation package?

Tags: wix, shortcut

The start menu for shortcuts in Win7 uses a hierarchical structure while that in Win10 uses a flat structure.  I am looking for help on how to write the code in a WIX installer project that creates the hierarchical shortcut structure if the OS is Win7 and the flat structure if the OS is Win10.

In WIX, the start menu shortcut is defined using a Directory element with an ID of 'ProgramMenuFolder' (e.g. see [this document](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html)).  All articles I have found never define this element more than once.  Any time i try to define this element twice (e.g. inside different Fragments, Features, Components) then I get various error messages including the Candle error ""Duplicate symbol 'Directory:ProgramMenuFolder' found".

My question is, is it possible to have the same WIX built MSI installer create a hierarchical start menu shortcut structure if installing on Win7 but a flat start menu shortcut structure if installing on Win10? If so, can you provide details of the WIX code that is needed to do this?

ThanX!

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Its is not related to the OS version.

As Candle error implies that you are trying to set "ProgramMenuFolder" Directory twice in the same project.

When you use this directory inside different Fragments, Features, Components try to use the directory attribute (directory = "ProgramMenuFolder").

If you want to use it as hierarchical structure this directory should be under "TARGETDIR" Directory only, same for all other Predefined directories.

Answer (score 0):

It took some time but here is how I resolved the problem. In Win7 using the VS2010 installer, the shortcuts added by my installation package (i.e. MSI file) were nested as follows:

```
All Programs  
    CompanyName  
        ProductName  
            Version#
                App.exe  
                App.exe.config  
                App.pdf
```

The problem is that Win10 does not support the above hierarchical/nested structured.  The best you can get is a flat structure such as follows:

```
All Programs  
    Product Name - Version#  
        App.exe  
        App.exe.config  
        App.pdf
```

So I wanted to my WIX installer to use the hierarchical/nested shortcut structure when  installing on Win7 but then, when installing on Win10, to use the flat shortcut structure.  It took some time but I was able to get something working using two FEATURE elements each with it's own CONDITION element.  The first FEATURE used the hierarchical start menu shortcut structure for Win7 and earlier OS's.  The second FEATURE used the flat start menu shortcut structure for Win8 and later OS's. In short, the first FEATURE element set 'LEVEL=0' and then used a CONDITION element to set 'LEVEL=1' only if the OS was Win7 or earlier.   Similarly, the second FEATURE element set 'LEVEL=0' and then used a CONDITION element to set 'LEVEL=1) only if the OS was Win8 or later.  This solution still had a few problems to correct, was taking too much time to get right, and in the end I scrapped it for a simpler solution.

I was trying to adapt the Win7 installation process to Win10 and this was causing problems with the start menu shortcuts.   The solution was to reverse my thinking and to instead adapt the installation process for Win10 to Win7.  More specifically, it is very easy to program WIX to install the start menu flat shortcut structure imposed by Win10.  This start menu flat shortcut structure will also work with Win7 and earlier OS's.  So my solution was simply to use the same start menu flat shortcut structure for all supported operating systems.

A tale of woe from someone who has just started learning WIX :):):)

Ian